# Authentication error in google shopping search API

Tags: google-search-api, google-shopping-api

I want to use [Google Shopping Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/shopping/search/v1/getting_started.html) for products search. I have followed all the steps stated in document. First I created a google account, then went to [GOOGLE APIs console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/?api=shopping) to create a project and got an `API key`. I want to use this service as publishers in the Google Affiliate Network who can use the API to access product offers from their advertisers of choice.
Then I signed up at google affliate network to get `pid`. Then I send request to some advertisers to join their program from my affiliate admin panel. Now I have one advertiser approved. Now on this [document](http://code.google.com/apis/shopping/search/v1/getting_started.html), it states that to request feed to access products from google affiliate network advertisers of publisher I have to use the following url

```
https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/source/products
```

Where `source` in the url is replaced by `gan:mypublisherid` after putting this my url looks like

```
https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/gan:myid/products?key=mykey&country=US
```

But When I access this url i found following json error

```
{
"error": {
 "errors": [
  {
"domain": "global",
"reason": "conditionNotMet",
"message": "authentication is required for GAN",
"locationType": "header",
"location": "If-Match"
}
],
"code": 412,
"message": "authentication is required for GAN"
}
}
```

Now my question is how to get authenticated? Is my url is correct or there is some thing other way to do this?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this [article](http://code.google.com/apis/shopping/search/v1/getting_started.html#gan-authentication). The last part i.e. authentication.

You have to get an access token before using the API. You can either use OAuth or Client Login token. To get a token using Client login you can use [cURL](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/using_cURL.html). Remember to put servicetype as `shoppingapi` as the document says.